# How to modify ".strings" file by unix shell command(or command tool) in the iOS project?

Tags: ios, bash, shell

I want to dynamically modify the "xxx.strings" file by a shell script in iOS project.

They are key-value files.Is there some way to replace the value with the key?

1.The "InfoPlist.**strings**" file contents like this:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "WinTraining";
```

some one wants to change "WinTraining" to "eDetailing", like this:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "eDetailing";
```

2.And there same muti line files named "Localizable.**strings**" like this:

```
"Item" = "Item";
"ProductName" = "Product Name";
"Today" = "Today";
"NetworkError" = "Unable to connect to the network, please check the network";
"UploadComplete" = "Upload complete";
"Updating" = "Updating,Please wait...";
```

I want to modify the ".strings" file in my CI environment(jenkins),diffrient jenkins's jobs is built for diffrient customers) . In iOS project "CFBundleDisplayName" is used to set the app name, different customer requires different app name, so I need to change the "InfoPlist.string" file. "Localizable.strings",same situation.

Comment: Could you please supply sample input and output for the script?

Comment: what exactly do you want to modify?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just lookup your localized dynamically, if you have some strings which are dynamic anyway?

Comment: @ShellFish, thanks for reminding. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Thanks to Kazuki and MeetTitan, I found the better way by your prompts.
I also used the `sed` command to replace the values with the keys,Like this:

#### InfoPlist.strings:

```
 key=CFBundleDisplayName
 newvalue=\"eDetailing\"
 sed -i -e "s/${key} *\=.*\;/${key} = ${newvalue}\;/" InfoPlist.strings
```

#### Localizable.strings:

```
 key=\"Item\"
 newvalue=\"The\ Item\"
 sed -i -e "s/${key} *\=.*\;/${key} = ${newvalue}\;/" Localizable.strings
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `sed` command, you can try:

```
sed -i 's/\"WinTraining\"/\"eDetailing\"/' InfoPlist.strings
```

The sed command should also work on your Localizable.strings as well. To replace something else use:

`sed -i 's/STRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR/STRING_TO_REPLACE_SEARCH_STRING_WITH/'`

Be sure to escape quotes and such.

Comment: They are key-value files.Is there some way to replace the value with the key?

Answer (score 0):

Add a script like the following to your Jenkins job settings

```
mv $WORKSPACE/InfoPlist.strings $WORKSPACE/InfoPlist.strings.orig
sed -e 's/WinTraining/eDetailing/' $WORKSPACE/InfoPlist.strings.orig > $WORKSPACE/InfoPlist.strings
```